# Differences between 'as well as' and 'together with'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

1. Now-a-days, many hotels and restaurants are being established where local foods *together with* western foods are being supplied.
2. Now-a-days, many hotels and restaurants are being established where local foods *as well as* western foods are being supplied.

Which words (*as well as* and *together with*) sound natural for above case? What are the differences in meaning of these two sentences?

Comment: Food processing factories supply foods. Restaurants usually ***serve*** them.

Comment: "nowadays" doesn't need hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"as well as" is for another thing **in addition to** something else.

> This shelter accommodates dogs as well as cats.
>
> To get hired in the Canadian government you need to be proficient in English as well as French.

"together with" is for things that are **alongside** each other.

> The factory made chips together with other fast food.
>
> We had a class which dealt with math together with science at our middle school.
>
> The store sold groceries together with cleaning supplies and drugs before it had to close down.